# past progressive or past simple: worked or working

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

In the following sentences, could the past progressive be replaced by the past simple with no change of meaning? Is there a preferred form?

> We **were working** / **worked** hard yesterday because the boss wanted to see the project finished.

> We **were cooking** / **cooked** all morning because we had 15 people coming for lunch.

Comment: **It depends on what you want to say. Not grammar.**

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are perfectly idiomatic.

The past simple is more likely in most contexts. But if you wanted to emphasise the extent of your labours or were answering a question such as:

**What were you doing yesterday that took you all that time?**

It is likely that you would use the past progressive:

**We were working hard all day yesterday.....**

Comment: But what dictates the use of the past progressive rather than the past simple in "What were you doing yesterday that took you all that time?" in the first place?

Comment: Nothing dictates the use of the past progressive. The question is whether its use is more appropriate to the context. My example simply illustrates when it might be more appropriate.